# VCR creates a file but doesn't put anything in it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faraday, vcr

I am trying to test a parser that uses Faraday with VCR.  The test passes the first time and creates an empty cassette.  When I run it again it hits the empty cassette and fails. I have tested the parser in the console and it works every time.  Here is the code:

**Config**

```
require 'vcr'
# require 'webmock/rspec'
RSpec.configure do |config|
VCR.configure do |c|
c.cassette_library_dir = 'spec/vcr'
c.default_cassette_options = { record: :new_episodes}
c.hook_into :webmock
end
```

**Parser Class**

```
  require 'zip
   require 'net/http'

   class Parser
   attr_reader :response

 def initialize
   @response = Faraday.get("http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/premarket/ftparea/public.zip")
 end

 def unzipped_file
   Zip::InputStream.open(StringIO.new(response.body)) do |io|
     while (entry = io.get_next_entry)
       lines = io.read.split(/\r\n/)
     end
     lines
   end
 end

 def headers
   %w(name address1 address2 address3 city state zip phone fax)
 end

 def split_lines
   unzipped_file.map { |line| line.split("|") }
 end

 def records
   split_lines.map { |line| headers.zip(line).to_h }
 end
    end
```

**Spec File**

```
describe Parser do
describe 'api call' do
 it 'gets a response from api' do
 VCR.use_cassette('parser') do
 response = Parser.new.records

 expect(response.first.class).to eq Hash
 end
```

end
 end
end

Comment: I believe VCR only serializes JSON & Yaml by default - you'd have to write your own for a zip file.

Comment: Anthony - do you have an example of what this serializer would look like?

Comment: Why did you commented webmock require?
And try to move VCR.configure block out of Rspec.configure